# Hinge loss is the tightest convex upper bound on the 0-1 loss

Tags: svm, loss-functions, hinge-loss

I have read many times that the hinge loss is the tightest convex upper bound on the 0-1 loss (e.g. [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml14/slides/lecture2.pdf), [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eethanf/teaching/ItSLT_16/lectures/lec7_no_anim.pdf) and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-019-01387-y)). However, I have never seen a formal proof of this statement. How can we formally define the hinge loss, 0-1 loss and the concept of tightness between functions to prove this statement?

Comment: did you find answer?! , I am looking for the same question:(.

Comment: @missRan I did not. You could up vote the question so it gains more visibility :)